# Pandas apply function on multiple columns

Tags: pandas, function, dataframe

I am trying to apply a function to every column in a dataframe, when I try to do it on just a single fixed column name it works. I tried doing it on every column, but when I try passing the column name as an argument in the function I get an error.

How do you properly pass arguments to apply a function on a data frame?

```
def result(row,c):

     if  row[c] >=0 and row[c] <=1:
         return 'c'

     elif row[c] >1 and row[c] <=2:
         return 'b'

     else:
         return 'a'


cols = list(df.columns.values)

for c in cols

     df[c] = df.apply(result, args = (c),  axis=1)

TypeError: ('result() takes exactly 2 arguments (21 given)', u'occurred at index 0')
```

Input data frame format:

```
d = {'c1': [1, 2, 1, 0], 'c2': [3, 0, 1, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
      c1   c2
0     1     3
1     2     0
2     1     1
3     0     2
```

Comment: is this a dummy function or the actual one? if actual, i dont think you need apply here. if you can share some data v/s expected we can help

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass the column name to apply. As you only want to check if values of the columns are in certain range and should return `a, b or c`. You can make the following changes.

```
def result(val):

     if  0<=val<=1:
         return 'c'
     elif 1<val<=2:
         return 'b'
     return 'a'


cols = list(df.columns.values)

for c in cols

     df[c] = df[c].apply(result)
```

> Note that this will replace your column values.

A faster way is [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
import numpy as np
values = ['c', 'b']
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = np.select([0<=df[col]<=1, 1<df[col]<=2], values, default = 'a')
```

Comment: I get the following error when running this : ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: The data frame I have is all float values